# How peoples create video highlights from matches?

Tags: video-recording

I want to know how peoples create those fancy highlights for a match, as match goes for over 90 minutes and highlights show every thing in just 3 to 4 minutes ... which tools or techniques are used to create those highlights ? I want to create those ones for my self and for my channel .... any one idea please share with me

Comment: By match do you mean football match or the like? You create a highlight reel by editing and perhaps make it fancier with motion graphics and music. People go to school or self study for years to learn these skills. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Alot of times there is someone who tracks the game and writes down specific times. Say there was a goal at the 35 min mark, they jot down "Goal - team name - 35:26" or something related to that. Then later on they have a list of different times as well as different events (goals, saves, close shots, etc.) and choose the best ones. Then the editor opens a recording of the whole game in Final Cut Pro or Adobe Premiere and goes to those times, trims them quickly, add cool transitions and exports. I have experience with it and for a 3 period hockey game, I can normally edit and export in under an hour. The log file saves you from having to scrub through and find the best shots.

Answer (score 0):

Creating game/match highlights really all comes down to logging the game. You need to identify the in and out times of all of the relevant plays. Depending on how many simultaneous games you are recording, how quickly you need to turn around the highlight package to air, and several other factors determine what tools you will use. If you are just working on one game and have lots of time to turn around the package, you could probably get away with creating your own Excel logging template and edit with any software. However, the more simultaneous games and the quicker you need to get to air, the more you will need specialized software. You will also need to add more thorough and accurate metadata, so that you can search to find the right shots for the highlight package.

There are sport specific logging tools that allow you to quickly build up the metadata about the shot ([like this one from Dalet](http://derafwxer04zs.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/images/Dalet_Sports_Logger.png)) and integrate with editing and asset management systems.